# Port is not being redirected when it is active from 8080 to 80

Tags: glassfish, apache2

I am using glassfish and apache2 server I've used below commands

```
1) sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

2) sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

3) sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i enp1s0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

4) sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80800 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

But the problem is when glassfish is stopped i am able to redirect localhost:8080 to 80 port but when glassfish is started it doesn't redirect to 80 port

Thanks in advance

Comment: TYPO in 4th command it is --dport 8080 not 80800

Answer (score 1):

```
4) sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80800 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

The port number is wrong here. It should be 8080

Comment: yes that is typo i've updte in comment that i've used 8080 not 80800